# Can i get value of omnibox in my extension without setting any Keyword in manifest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to get the value of the Omnibox search bar but requires me to set a keyword first in the manifest. I would just like to read whatever user is searching for

Comment: Your code looks fine, should work.

Comment: You can't. See [How to add eventlistener on keypress to chrome's address bar - Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/33673870)